# Python 2.7 serial port RS232 data read (2 Byte)

Tags: python, serial-port

I have this code.

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate=2400,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

ser.open()
ser.isOpen()
print ser.portstr

x=ser.read(1)
print type(x)

while True:

        print x

        time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this code I get as out rectangular characters.(I dont know how to describe it - maybe some type of block element???).

So I know that the data which I receive consist of:

```
bit  0  1  2  3  4   5   6    7
LSB  D0 D1 D2 D3 D4  D5  par "0"
MSB  D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 D11 par "1"
```

Whole data are in 2 Byte. In first byte are 8bits ( D0-D5 are data, par following word on odd parity, stop bits two).

My question is how I can receive a read this type of data and how convert it to decimal...

Thanks

Comment: x=ser.read(1) will only read 1 byte. The rectangular characters are probably just the ascii equivalent of a low-value byte < 32(decimal). Try printing hex(x) or hex(x[0]) instead.

Comment: When I use hex(x) or  hex(x[0])  I get TypeError hex() argument cant be converted to hex

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
binaryReceived = ser.read(2)
if len(binaryReceived)>=2:
    decimalReceived = (binaryReceived[0]&0x1f) | (binaryReceived[1]&0x1f)<<5
    print decimalReceived
else:
    print "two bytes not received"
```

Comment: thanks for answer. When I used your code I dont nothing. Blinking cursor

Comment: print len(x)  is 1 and type of x is str...when I used ser.read(2) I get nothing

Comment: Are you sure you have correct baud rate? Two stop bits is unusual, and doesn't matter if you are only receiving if it is one: have you tried one?

Comment: I have 12 bit A/D and every sample must be passed in 2 Byte and for every byte must be received 11 bits (1xstart,8xdata,2xstop). For the selected sampling rate 100 samples/sec is necassary every sec 2*100*10=2200 bits. This is reason why I have baud rate 2400...Yes I tried stopbist_one but still nothing

Comment: I use asynchonnous comunication. Can be some problem when I use standart serial port rs232 on my PC? I think in conection of serial port

Comment: What is the sending device, is that something you created? Have you tried using a PC as a serial terminal to receive the data, to check it is is what you expect? Or use the PC to send some known data, verify that your python code receives it correctly.

Comment: If you aren't completely sure about the correctness of either end, use a PC serial terminal program to verify either that the sent data is correct or that you can send data into your code. Having verified that one end works, check the other end against that.

Comment: Any reason you can't run the serial link faster, e.g. 9600 baud? then your data transfers will complete more quickly. And I would use a single stop bit, if there were no reason not to.